# Trying to list files of a directory in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to list all files of a specific directory, but when I run the code:

```
    String pt = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Musi";
    File dir = new File(pt);
    System.out.println("Path of directory= "+dir);

    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    System.out.println("Lenght of the array: "+filelist.length);

    String[] NameFiles = new String[filelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < NameFiles.length; i++)
    {
        NameFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
    }

  return NameFiles;
```

the array **filelist** has only 1 position occupied which has the **.thumbnail** directory, but I have 2 more files which are mp3

The path returned by **pt** is **/storage/emulated/0/Musi** which is ok
Lastly I checked in the file browser of android studio and I got my two .mp3 files in the same directory path

[image: Files in the emulated phone]

How can I make these files show up in the array?

Comment: What's your targetSDK and what permissions you have before running that code?

Comment: True i forgot to specify that i have both permissions to read and write from internal and external storage in the manifest, the targetted SDK is 30 and the minimum is 16

Comment: What is Android version of used device?

Comment: `1 position occupied wich has the .thumbnail dir` Then why is that not shown in Device File Explorer?

Comment: @blackapps Nice question i'm going to double check the file explorer...I am using Android 11

Comment: If your app did not place those files there you will not see them as you are not thr owner.

Comment: @blackapps but what about any other mp3 players that you can use on android phones, they just read folders and search for mp3 files to play, i don't get why this doesn't work without giving the permissions through the app explorer on the emulator, probably has something to do with requiring permissions at run time i guess

Comment: It has to do with Android 11 on your device which is very picky concerning the owner of  files. Unless you request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to get all files access.